# Como criar uma Janela JavaFX sem os três botoes padrão(Minimizar,Maximizar e Fechar)?

Tags: javafx

É basicamente o que esta na pergunta, eu queria uma tela sem esses 3 botões,vamos dizer que sem aquela borda que vem padrão  em basicamente todas as janelas que se abre no windows, e que vem com esses 3 botões, e que iniciasse em full screen.Pesquisei na net e não encontrei nada parecido.Idéias?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Então, nada kkkk pq nao encontrei nada que pudesse retirar isso. Ou aparecia de outras linguagens , ou coiisas não relacionadas.

Comment: @RORSCHACH a pergunta parece bem curta, mas é totalmente possivel responder, ele não necessário esta querendo alterar algo, mas sim fazer algo baseado na API do JavaFX, assim como o Deins respondeu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode definir o estilo utilizando o método `initStyle()` que recebe um [StageStyle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html) do seu [Stage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html).

Ex.:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Text text = new Text(10, 40, "Hello World!");
        text.setFont(new Font(40));
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(text));

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED)

        stage.setTitle("Welcome to JavaFX!"); 
        stage.setScene(scene); 
        stage.sizeToScene(); 
        stage.show(); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Os valores possíveis são:

**DECORATED**

> Defines a normal Stage style with a solid white background and platform decorations.

> Define um estilo de palco com um fundo branco sólido

---

**TRANSPARENT**

> Defines a Stage style with a transparent background and no decorations.

> Define um estilo de palco com um fundo transparente e com decorações.

---

**UNDECORATED**

> Defines a Stage style with a solid white background and no decorations.

> Define um estilo de palco com um fundo branco e sem decorações

---

**UNIFIED**

> Defines a Stage style with platform decorations and eliminates the border between client area and decorations.

> Define um estilo de palco com decorações e elimina a borda entre a área do cliente e as decorações

---

**UTILITY**

> Defines a Stage style with a solid white background and minimal platform decorations used for a utility window.

> Define um estilo de palco com um fundo branco sólido e decorações minímas usadas por uma tela de utilitário.

---

Para deixar em tela cheia, pode chamar o método [setFullScreen(boolean value)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setFullScreen-boolean-), `true` para iniciar em tela cheia, false caso contrário

Comment: Opa muito obrigado,  funcionou mt bem, e era bem isso que eu precisava.Thanks for that.